# SQLiteOpenHelper - Where do I store initial data?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert, sqliteopenhelper

I have some initial data to insert in my database. I've added it to my custom SQLiteOpenHelper class.

```
package com.company.database;

import android.content.Context; import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase; import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TABLE_NAMES = "names";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "my.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String TABLE_NAMES_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAMES + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COLUMN_NAME + " VARCHAR NOT NULL);";

    private static final String TABLE_NAMES_INSERT = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAMES
            + "(" + COLUMN_NAME + ")" + " VALUES "
            + "('Antony'),"
            + "('Benny'),"
            + "('Carol'),"
            + "('Daniel'),"
            // ... AND SO ON ...

    public MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(TABLE_NAMES_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        dropTable(database);
        onCreate(database);
    }

    private void dropTable(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAMES);
    } }
```

Please note the insert statements. The quantity of names will increase and i don't want to keep this mess.

What should i do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can "ship" your database along with your application. That way, you can preset the details without the having to commit them when the user downloads them. However, note that the application file size may increase depending on how large the data is. A library you can use to accomplish this is the SQLite Asset Helper (link: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

Answer (score 0):

You could create the database on your computer, include it in the APK, and load it in the app when it's run for the first time.

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/